# Office365 add-in could not popup window on Outlook 2016 with displayDialogAsync method

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, add-in, office-js

I'm writing an add-in for Calendar and the following code is working on Browser
 Office.initialize = function () {

```
        $('#continueBtn').click(function () {
            var url = "https://xxx";
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 75, width: 40 });

        });
```

but when I test it on Outlook 2016 client on Win10, the click event is not working.  When I attach debugger on the window, there's no error message shown

The method Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', 1.4) return true in debugger, so I have no idea what's the issue is?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Could you please let us know the build number of your outlook 2016?

Comment: What is the url that you are going to? Has it been added to the <appdomains> section in the manifest? Does the dialog pop up? Or just the receive message not working? Do you get an error in the AsyncCallback of DisplayDialogAsync? If you can repro with a very small add-in, can you upload somewhere for us to repro?

Comment: The Outlook 2016 client build no is 1806(10228.20080)
Add to appdomains is not working because the sso domain is configurable.

The dialog popup but could not send message to parent window and no error could be found.

Comment: For example
1. popup to ssodemo1.zoom.us
2. redirect to sso site www.ssodemo1.com in popup window
3. input user name / password
4. validate and jump back to www.zoom.us ssocnofirm page
5. the ssoconfirm page would send message to parent 
6. after process the message, the message would call window.opener.close to close the popup window
The issue is window.operner.close is not working